# How to merge multiple json rows from mysql to 1 json object

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am facing problem I have merging multiples rows to single JSON object.
spouse I have a table

```
| ID | columnJson                  | bookingID|
|----| ----------                  | ---------|
| 1  | {"ID":1,"a":"abd","b":"xyz"}| 1001     |
| 2  | {"ID":2,"a":"BD","b":"naod"}| 1002     |
| 3  | {"ID":1,"a":"abc"}          | 1001     |
```

How can I fetch bookingID 1001 as below in php

```
{"ID":1,"a":"abc","b":"xyz"}
```

I tried this from an other question but in my case I got no luck

```
SET @json = ( SELECT CONCAT( "'", GROUP_CONCAT( columnJson SEPARATOR "','" ), "'" ) FROM booking_columns_history );
SET @q = CONCAT( "SELECT JSON_MERGE_PATCH(", @json, ") AS JSON_MERGE_PATCH;" );
PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: Parse (JSON_TABLE), aggregate (GROUP BY or DISTINCT), reconstruct (JSON_OBJECTAGG).

Comment: @Akina I'm little confuse, can please write an answer?